# Running Python Script from inside DXL/DOORS

Tags: python, ibm-doors

How do you run a python script from inside DXL/DOORS? I attempted using the system() command but only gotten errors.

Comment: aand...which errors ?

Comment: You need better Googling skills as I easily found the answer to you question on the DOORS/DXL forums: `You shoud pass in the name of a temporary file to which the python script stores its output. Then you read the file from DXL after the python finishes.`. Check out Mathias's answer **[here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014900310)**.

Comment: I did see Mathias's answer but it did not work for me.  Thank you very much

Comment: I am getting an error "create process failed.

Comment: Please include all the errors and your attempts in your original question.

Comment: The error message I am getting is "CreateProcess failed."  I am using the system("C:\\myPython.exe H:\\myscript.py)

Comment: Roman, all I am trying to do is run the python script without passing any additional information

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying your command string `C:\\myPython.exe H:\\myscript.py` in the command line first, seeing if that works. If it does then it could be a permissions error (can't tell unless you have an error code to go with the CreateProcess error, as there are several types).

It might then be worth checking you can run any kind of command in the command line from DOORs (`system("notepad")` should do the trick)

If that doesn't work running DOORS as an admin may fix your issue, you can do this by going to the `doors.exe` right-clicking Properties -> Compatibility and selecting "Run this program as an administrator".